# For subspace $U$ of $V$ where $V$ is finite-dimensional, is $U = V$ if and only if $\dim U = \dim V$?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

**For subspace $U$ of $V$ where $V$ is finite-dimensional, $U = V$ if and only if $\dim U = \dim V$.**

A. Is the statement above true?

B. If true, is the following proof correct?

> Suppose $U = V$. Then $\dim U = \dim V$ by definition of dimension.
>
> Conversely, suppose $\dim U = \dim V = n$. Let $u_1, \dotsc, u_n$ be a basis of $U$. Since $U$ is a subspace of $V$, $u_1, \dotsc, u_n$ is linearly independent in $V$ and thus can be extended to a basis of $V$. However, since $u_1, \dotsc, u_n$ already contains $n$ vectors, there is nothing to add, hence it is already a basis of $V$. Since $U$ and $V$ share the same basis, $U = V$.

Comment: a) No and b) Yes :)

Comment: @RabMakh But U is subspace of V.

Comment: @RabMakh aren't they isomorphic?

Comment: A. is false if $V$ is not finite-diimensional.

Comment: Are all vector spaces in the problem finite-dimensional?

Comment: I edited my question to reflect $V$ is finite-dimensional (thus so is $U$, since $U$ is a subspace of $V$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement is true in finite dimensions. Your proof is essentially correct but just slightly unclear. A somewhat clearer way to say it: $u_1,\dots,u_n$ can be extended to a basis of $V$, but all bases of $V$ have cardinality exactly $n$, so $u_1,\dots,u_n$ is already a basis of $V$. Thus $U$ and $V$ have a common basis and are thus the same vector space.

The statement is false in infinite dimensions, because in this case the basis of $U$ may be a proper subset of a basis of $V$ even though both have the same cardinality.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is true, assuming that we are dealing with finite-dimensional spaces here.

Your proof is correct. You don't need to write that if $U=V$, them $\dim U=\dim V$ by definition of dimension. If two things are equal, everything that we can build from them will also be equal.

Comment: I accepted Ian's answer because it came 1 minute earlier and for formalizing my logic. Thank you for pointing out that if two things are equal, I don't need to state that some aspect of them is also equal by definition.

Comment: @tmakino That's what I would have done too: if I had to choose between two equally correct answers, I would choose the one that was posted first.